# how to split this dataset into train and validation set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to split dataset with sklearn because I don't think validation_split is working for me. Here's how im actually reading dataset:

```
input_sentences = []
output_sentences = []
output_sentences_inputs = []    #Translated data

count = 0
for line in open(r'/content/drive/My Drive/TEMPPP/123.txt', encoding="utf-8"):
    count += 1

    if count > NUM_SENTENCES:
        break

    if '\t' not in line:
        continue

    input_sentence, output = line.rstrip().split('\t')

    output_sentence = output + ' <eos>'
    output_sentence_input = '<sos> ' + output

    input_sentences.append(input_sentence)
    output_sentences.append(output_sentence)
    output_sentences_inputs.append(output_sentence_input)
```

Now im confused how to use scikit learn. For now this is what I did.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(input_sentences, output_sentences, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)
```

First thing, Is it the right approach????

If no? then how do I make the split?

If yes? then help me with this confusion:
I was passing input_sentences and output_sentences to my layers, now what do I need to pass???? Do I still pass input_sentences and output_sentences like before and train model with full dataset or do I need to only send xTrain and yTrain???? And xTest and yTest will never be passed  by layers, only used to validate?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it seems that what you're currently doing is correct.

No, you can forget about `input_sentences` and `output_sentences`, from now only use arrays that `train_test_split` creates.

If you're using ML algorithm that has a `fit()` method - this one will use `xTrain` and `yTrain`. The `predict()` method will take `xTest` and you use `yTest` to check accuracy of your predictions from `predict()` method. Say, calling `sklearn.metrics.r2_score(predictions, yTest)`.

Also please note that using multiple question marks to end your sentence makes it [sound interrogatory and impolite](https://dictionaryeyes.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/the-question-mark/). You're here asking for help so please watch your punctuation.

Comment: sorry, I will keep that in mind and will not use question marks. So after that, I replaced wherever there were input_sentences and output_sentences in my code with xTrain and yTrain. But now im confused how to modify my model.fit(). Btw here's link to a post where I have posted my code, please guide me how to make changes here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328054/how-to-split-dataset-and-use-it-with-lstm-seq2seq-model>

Comment: If you're using keras you're better off using [data generators](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly). Also, just a point of nit - usually it's not a great habit to make imports inline, with the exception of debug module. Put them all at the start of file so it's easy to understand what modules you're using.